# Windows Explorers crashes when opening more than 96 subdirectories

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, crash

I've created a directory with as many subdirectories as possible. But whenever I try to open the 97th directory Windows Explorer will crash. Im also not able to delete the main directory anymore since this will also make Windows Explorer crash.

Opening this Folder will work.
    C:\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a

Opening the subdirectory of this folder will make Windows Explorer crash. 
Does anyone have an idea what could cause this behavior?

I'm using 64 bit Windows 10

Comment: Another good question for miscrosoft support

Comment: create a crash dump and sahre the dmp, so that I can try to debug it. Here are the steps you should follow to generate dumps: http://pastebin.com/WACz5GBU

Answer (score 1):

There is a path length limit of 260 characters. But your path is 'only' 195 characters long. Anyway when you have paths that are this long you will run into windows API problems.

You can check this source to increase your path lengths and what not: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247(VS.85).aspx

Also you can get arounbd this limitation with `subst`: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491006.aspx you can assign a system drive to `C:\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a` and continue from there on.

Als you can try to access it from Windows Power Shell. I think it has less limitations (not sure about this though, but thought to say it anyway.)

Comment: I just tried using PowerShell.. It works fine! Even deleting it(which didnt work with explorer nor cmd) works with PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the crash is caused by a limit on the length of a path.

Windows only allows a certain amount of characters in a path.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: The limit is 260 characters. I haven't reached that limit.

Comment: Are you running 32bit or 64bit Windows?

Comment: I'm running 64 bit

Comment: How far do you want to chase this?
See if you can find the crash in Event Viewer and message the XML to me.

Comment: It's too long to be posted as a comment.

Comment: You could put it onto pastebin then link me it?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Q1jydgvL